# Why is this LINQ not finding an element two levels down?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am having trouble parsing the XML file (stripped down sample of XML in code snippet below). The error I am getting is

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XmlToLink.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I know my issue is in the XmlBarcodes = el.Element("Barcodes") area because when I comment that section out the Order Number, First & Last Name, and the ProductName are returned. I think it is because I am not drilling down to the BarcodeString correctly with LINQ but I have tried every variation of getting to that element that I could come up with so I am wondering if there is something else (not obvious to me) that is wrong with the syntax. What am I doing wrong?

```
    private static IEnumerable<XmlOrders> ParseXml()
    {            
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(GetXml());
        var query = from el in document.Root.Elements("Order")
                    select new XmlOrders
                    {
                        Id = (int)el.Element("Id"),
                        XmlBillingAddress = new XmlBillingAddress()
                        {
                            FirstName = (string)el.Element("BillingAddress").Element("FirstName"),
                            LastName = (string)el.Element("BillingAddress").Element("LastName"),
                        },

                        XmlOrderItems = el.Element("OrderItems")
                        .Elements("OrderItem")
                        .Select(orderItem => new XmlOrderItems()
                        {
                            ProductName = (string)orderItem.Element("ProductName")
                        }).ToList(),

                        //XmlBarcodes = el.Element("OrderItems").Element("OrderItem").Element("Barcodes")
                        XmlBarcodes = el.Element("Barcodes")
                        .Elements("Barcode")
                        .Select(barcode => new XmlBarcodes()
                        {
                            BarcodeNumber = (string)barcode.Element("CodeString")
                        }).ToList()
                    };

        return query;
    }

    private static String GetXml()
    {
        return @"<ArrayOfOrder>
          <Order>
            <Id>25057</Id>
            <OrderGuid />
            <BillingAddress>
              <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
              <LastName>Onetime</LastName>
            </BillingAddress>
            <OrderItems>
              <OrderItem>
                <ProductName>High Mileage Oil Change</ProductName>
                <Barcodes>
                  <Barcode>
                    <CodeString>A5834A7</CodeString>
                  </Barcode>
                </Barcodes>
              </OrderItem>
            </OrderItems>
           </Order>
          <Order>
            <Id>25058</Id>
            <OrderGuid />
            <BillingAddress>
              <FirstName>Christopher</FirstName>
              <LastName>Tracey</LastName>
            </BillingAddress>
            <OrderItems>
              <OrderItem>
                <ProductName>Conventional Oil Change</ProductName>
                <Barcodes>
                  <Barcode>
                    <CodeString>A7E32B3</CodeString>
                  </Barcode>
                  <Barcode>
                    <CodeString>A6F73BA</CodeString>
                  </Barcode>
                </Barcodes>
              </OrderItem>
            </OrderItems>
           </Order>
        </ArrayOfOrder>";
    }
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in XmlToLink.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you're not drilling down to the `Barcodes` element under `OrderItem`. Don't forget that `el` will refer to an `Order` element, but you want the `Order -> OrderItems -> OrderItem -> Barcodes -> Barcode` element. I suspect you want:

```
XmlBarcodes = el.Element("OrderItems")
                .Elements("OrderItem")
                .Elements("Barcodes")
                .Elements("Barcode")
                .Select(barcode => new XmlBarcodes {
                     BarcodeNumber = (string) barcode.Element("CodeString")
                })
                .ToList()
```

However, given that this is *really* part of an `OrderItem`, you should perhaps change your `XmlOrderItems` class to include the barcodes.

(As an aside, it seems odd that your classnames are plural - each `XmlBarcodes` object is only *one* barcode, right?)

Comment: You are correct. There can only be one barcode per OrderItem so I'll fix that as well as a few other naming issues. Thanks.